# read/write with c from/in file

Tags: c, file

I want to read from a file and then add/substract to/from the characters that are in the file, a number given by the user. Also the user will decide if the program will add or subtract. My problem is, that I can't read and write the first character in the for loop. I read the first character, but I write at the end of what is already written in the file. I guess that I can't use fgetc and fputc in the same loop, or that I need to send *fp, back in the start of the file after the restart of the procedure (through a menu).

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str[50],keystr[50],*p,c;
FILE *fp;
int i,k,key,buff1,buff2,choice;

start:

printf("Make a choice\n1.Add\n2.Sub\n3.Exit\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
if(choice==3) goto end;
getchar();
printf("\nGimme the key");
fgets(keystr,50,stdin);

key=0;
i=0;

while(keystr[i])
{
    key=key+keystr[i];
    i++;
}
printf("\n%d",key);
printf("\nDwste onoma arxeiou");
fgets(str,50,stdin);

fp=fopen(str,"r+");
if (fp==NULL) printf("error");
buff1=0;
buff2=0;
for(;;)
{
    if((c=fgetc(fp))==EOF) break;
    buff1=c;
    if(choice==1)
    {
            buff1=buff1+key;
            c=buff1;
            fputc(c,fp);
            printf("\n%d",buff1);
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
            buff1=buff1-key;
            c=buff1;
            fputc(c,fp);
            printf("\n%d",buff1);
    }
}
goto start;
end:
fclose(fp);
printf("\nBye");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Check this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ungetc/ Should be enough.

Comment: Curious here - why use `goto` instead of function calls? I've heard of "spaghetti code" but never seen it implemented, and was taught to never do this.

Comment: @C.Lang Agree. goto is famous evil

Comment: I think you can use fseek something like below

Comment: if((c=fgetc(fp))==EOF) break;
    buff1=c;
    if(choice==1)
    {
            buff1=buff1+key;
            c=buff1;
            fputc(c,fp);
            printf("\n%d",buff1);
    }

Comment: @C.Lang why not use goto? Spaghetti is going up and down using goto all the time. When I just want to make a jump to the end and a jump to the start, I really like goto. Since I learnt assembly 8086, in which I could only make jumps (like goto), I changes my opinion for it ^^

Comment: @C.Lang Using goto, you get rid of the extra "{}" of a while or a for loop. If you are going to use goto without messing up the mind of the reader, then do it!! It's nice, easy and free :p

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966

Comment: I just finished my assembly class and at the beginning we used `jmp`s for that purpose but only to get us up and running. Later we went to sub-procs then to external `call`s. In really simple situations in code that no one will have to maintain I guess it's fine. I'm just a product of my education:

Comment: I did for homework in assembly 8086 the Simon Sais game. http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/simon-says-game.html with graphics to vga and file handling. There were so many if statements->jumps that it started to hurt xD

Comment: @AdriánLópez - nice link. I've read another I can't seem to find where it suggests if `goto` is so bad then why does it even exist. The author's conclusion was similar saying smart usage of any language feature should be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fgetc` and `fputc` for the same file in the same loop, but you have to remember that after you called `fgetc` the file pointer is positioned at the next character so that the `fputc` call will write over the next character and not the one just read. Of course, `fputc` will also increase the file pointer, leading you to read and write every second character.

If you want to overwrite the character you just read, you have to use `fseek` to rewind the position one step.

Answer (score 1):

I think fseek will work something like below:

```
int opr =0;
for (;;)
{
fseek(fp,opr,SEEK_SET)
if((c=fgetc(fp))==EOF) break;
buff1=c;
if(choice==1)
{
        buff1=buff1+key;
        c=buff1;
        fseek(fp,opr,SEEK_SET); 
        fputc(c,fp);
        printf("\n%d",buff1);
        opr++:
}
else
{
 ....  //Similarly for else loop.
}
}
```